# How do I template a class using an instance of another templated class?

Tags: c++, class, gpio

I have a gpio class which is templated:

```
template <gpio_types::port_t PORT, uint32_t PIN>
class gpio {};
```

I want create a class that takes a `gpio` instance as a template. The problem is in the line below.

```
template <uart_types::flexcomm PERIPH, int RX_BUF_LEN, gpio<gpio_types::port_t PORT, uint32_t PIN> TX_PIN>
class uart_shared_n_block {};
```

In the end, I want to use it like this:

```
gpio<gpio_types::P1, 13> tx;
auto uart = uart_shared_n_block<uart_types::FC_4,2048,tx>();
```

How to template the `uart_shared_n_block` class properly?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#6 http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#7

Comment: What version of C++ can you use?  Untill C++20, you can't do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use anything more recent than C++14

Comment: Side note: Consider to use `libgpiod` C++ bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
gpio<gpio_types::P1, 13> tx;
```

declares `tx` to be an object of type `<gpio<gpio_types::P1, 13>>`. `gpio<gpio_types::P1, 13>` is not a tempalte, it is a concrete type. If you want to pass that type as parameter to the `uart_shared_n_block` then, that would be:

```
template <uart_types::flexcomm PERIPH, int RX_BUF_LEN, 
          typename T>
class uart_shared_n_block {};
```

Then you can instantiate it via

```
auto uart = uart_shared_n_block<uart_types::FC_4,2048,gpio<gpio_types::P1, 13>>();
```

or

```
auto uart = uart_shared_n_block<uart_types::FC_4,2048,decltype(tx)>();
```

If you actually want to pass an instance, not a type, then I misunderstood the question ;).

Comment: Thanks ! However how do I call a member function belonging to `tx`?

Comment: like so : `TX_PIN tx; tx.init_mux(1);`

Comment: @Victor `T tx; tx.init_mux(1);` ?